# Quartz scheduler - Cron Not Running

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler

I am trying to run a scheduler which will update dates in my database table. The cron is starting but it is not starting the job!

My cron file -->

```
    package Crons.Schedulers;


import org.quartz.CronTrigger;
import org.quartz.Scheduler;
import org.quartz.SchedulerFactory;
import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;
import org.quartz.JobDetail;


public class WeeklySchedule{
  public WeeklySchedule()throws Exception {
    SchedulerFactory sf=new StdSchedulerFactory();
    Scheduler sched=sf.getScheduler();
    sched.start();
    JobDetail jd=new JobDetail("WeeklyTask","Weekly",WeeklyJob.class);
    CronTrigger ct=new CronTrigger("cronTrigger","group2","0 57 16 * * ?");
    sched.scheduleJob(jd,ct);

  }
  public static void main(String args[]){
    try{    
    new WeeklySchedule();
    }catch(Exception e){}
  }
}
```

The output shown is -->

```
    INFO  SimpleThreadPool(initialize:247) - Job execution threads will use class loader of thread: main
INFO  QuartzScheduler(<init>:195) - Quartz Scheduler v.1.5.2 created.
INFO  RAMJobStore(initialize:138) - RAMJobStore initialized.
INFO  StdSchedulerFactory(instantiate:1014) - Quartz scheduler 'DefaultQuartzScheduler' initialized from default resource file in Quartz package: 'quartz.properties'
INFO  StdSchedulerFactory(instantiate:1018) - Quartz scheduler version: 1.5.2
INFO  QuartzScheduler(start:400) - Scheduler DefaultQuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
```

I have no idea what is going wrong as I am using quartz for the first time. 
What can be the possible reason?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

this line

```
CronTrigger ct=new CronTrigger("cronTrigger","group2","0 57 16 * * ?");
```

says your job'll start at 16:57. see this [Quartz CronTrigger Tutorial](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/tutorials/crontrigger.html)

Comment: Thakyou for your reply.  Before  running the cron I change the system time to 16:57.

Comment: If you want to thank for a useful answer, then click the upvote button (upper triangle left to the answer, with a hint which says: "This answer is useful").